# jQuery scrollTop several css and animate changes

Tags: jquery, css-position, scrolltop

Some new problems occured. I want to change several items by scrolling a specific amount.

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 160) {
        $('#test').css({
            'position' : 'fixed',
            'top' : '0'
        })
        $('#test2').animate({
            'width' : '105px',
            'margin-left' : '20px'
        })
    } else {
        $('#test').css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'top' : '100px'
        })
        $('#test2').animate({
            'width' : '0px',
            'margin-left' : '0px'
        })
    }
    });
});
```

The #test div perfectly works. It changes to position: fixed when you scroll 160px. And if you scroll back it gets absolute.
But #test2 just changes its width once. When I scroll back, nothing changes.

Comment: from which value does it animate?

Comment: #test2 starts from value width: 0 and margin-left: 0

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 4 semicolons:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 160) {
        $('#test').css({
            'position' : 'fixed',
            'top' : '0'
        });
        $('#test2').animate({
            'width' : '105px',
            'margin-left' : '20px'
        });
    } else {
        $('#test').css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'top' : '100px'
        });
        $('#test2').animate({
            'width' : '0px',
            'margin-left' : '0px'
        });
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry but this wasn't the problem :(

Comment: The #test2 animations are delayed in time. The #test css-changes work perfectly

Comment: `$('#test2').animate({'width' : '0px','margin-left' : '0px'},1000);` try that